# Do Proxy Servers cache a resource data based on the Uri?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

Do most popular proxy servers **cache the response data based on the Uri**? Also, lets exclude HTTP Headers like Cache-Control, etc... and assume they have been set to public, max-age: xxxx s-maxage: yyyyy etc...

So .. assuming the proxy server says 'this resource needs to be cached' .. what is the 'key'? the Uri?

so if i have

- www.somedomain.com
- www.somedomain.com/foo
- www.somedomain.com/foo?
- www.somedomain.com/foo?a=1
- www.somedomain.com/foo?a=1&b=2

they are all separate cached items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that most commonly it's a hash of things related to the URL, such as the name/address of the host, path, and sometimes other options such as cgi args.  [According to this FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/CacheDigests), Squid uses a hash of straight URL and the HTTP retrieval method to identify items already in the cache.

I think that the URLs you've listed would indeed cause separate cache items to be created in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with [Squid](http://squid-cache.org/). It definitely caches all your example URIs as separate objects. But please note that it's perfectly possible to configure Squid to not cache URIs matching certain pattern, such as those containing **?**.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is definitely a key parameter when it comes to caching.
In fact speaking as a web developer, one way to prevent caching of web resources is to append a random query string to the end of the URL.